# How can I create a grid using a list with generic objects in JavaScript (something like C# Reflection)

Tags: javascript, c#, reflection

Here is the deal: 
Our team is in a situation where we will lose access to our database (we will not be able to select, update or delete in our database directly (Client policies)).

But, we still can execute queries in our system. So we are starting to think about a way that we can execute queries in some specific page.

But there is a question:

Imagine executing a SELECT, the result can be anything, so the return must be a generic object. Can I make something like C# reflection in Javascript, to make a grid and show the results?

Like this pseudo-code:

```
foreach X in List{
   foreach Property in X {
     value1 = X.value1
     putValueOnGrid(value1)
     value2 = X.value2
     putValueOnGrid(value2)
   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much *all* objects in JavaScript are "generic". A simple `for ... in` loop will allow iteration through all object property names.

Comment: Right, so I could do a `for ... in` to get all property names of an object, create a header of a grid with them, and them make another `for ... in` to get the values of those properties. Did I get it? :D